# JSON pipe in Angular prints a blank string for "undefined" values

Tags: javascript, json, angular

When using the [json](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) pipe in Angular it prints a blank for `undefined` values.

```html
<pre>{{undefined | json}}</pre>
```

Outputs the following to the DOM

```html
<pre></pre>
```

This is not consistent with the JSON stringify function.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(undefined)); // prints "undefined"
```

How can I print the value "undefined" using the json pipe in Angular?

Comment: `undefined || "undefined" | json`? The [implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.2/packages/common/src/pipes/json_pipe.ts#L10-L33) is just `JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)`

Comment: What you really want to do is that when an undefined person arrives, it will be displayed indefinitely and not a blank space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in the controller set the value for that particular variable and if it's not undefined pipe json else just print undefined as value.

```
  {{ variable !== undefined ? (variable | json) : variable }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that `undefined` will be omitted from the results.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description

> If undefined, a Function, or a Symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array). JSON.stringify() can also just return undefined when passing in "pure" values like JSON.stringify(function(){}) or JSON.stringify(undefined).

I was running the following example in the JavaScript console, and was expecting to see the word "undefined" in the template.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(undefined)); // prints "undefined"
console.log(typeof JSON.stringify(undefined)); // does not print "string" it prints "undefined"
```

I was mistakenly thinking the console message "undefined" was a string value.